# Rails Acts_as_votable Gem Like/Unlike Buttons with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, button, rubygems, social-media-like

I'm new to Ruby On Rails, I used the acts_as_votable gem to create Like and Unlike Buttons to make Users like and unlike Posts but I can't make them change from Like to Unlike (and viceversa) and update the counter each time they click without refreshing the page. I tried following other kind-of-similar answers but I had no luck.
Without the messy changes I tried to do to implement Ajax my code looked like this:

Post Model acts_as_votable and User Model acts_as voter

Posts Controller has

```
def like
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end

def unlike
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.unliked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Routes have

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put 'like', to: "posts#like"
    put 'unlike', to: "posts#unlike"
  end
end
```

View has

```
<%= @post.get_likes.size%>
  <% if @post.get_likes.size ==1 %>
    person like this
  <% else %>
   people like this
<% end %>


<div class="btn-group">

  <% if (current_user.liked? @post) %>
    <%= link_to unlike_post_path(@post), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      Unlike
    <%end %>

  <% else %>

    <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :put, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
      Like
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

I read a lot of answers about Ajax but I was unable to replicate the results.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to point out your *posts controller to respond to js format*. Then the two actions in `posts_controller` become:

```
def like
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end

def unlike
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.unliked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

Second, you need to pass `remote: true` on your links:

```
 <div class="votes">
    <% if current_user.liked? @post %>
       <%= link_to unlike_post_path(@post), method: :get, remote: true, class: 'unlike_post' %>
     <% else %>
       <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :get, remote: true, class: 'like_post' %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
```

I change `method: :put` to `method: :get`, so change it in your `config/routes.rb`, and add a **class** to your links to bind it in js.

Finally, you need to create 2 views in `app/views/posts/`:

- like.js.erb

  ```
  $('.like_post').bind('ajax:success', function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript @post.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
     $(this).closest('.like_post').hide();
     $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Unlike", unlike_post_path(@post), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'unlike_post' %>');
  });
  ```
- unlike.js.erb

  ```
  $('.unlike_post').bind('ajax:success', function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript @post.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
     $(this).closest('.unlike_post').hide();
     $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(@post), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'like_post' %>');

  });
  ```

To handle update of count, I use a `.vote_count` class, so in your view:

```
<div class="vote_count">
  <%= @post.get_likes.size %>
</div>
```

So my view:

```
<div>
  <div class="vote_count">
    <%= @post.get_likes.size %>
  </div> 

  <div class="votes">
    <% if current_user.liked? @post %>
      <%= link_to unlike_post_path(@post), method: :get, remote: true, class: 'unlike_post' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :get, remote: true, class: 'like_post' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I edit my answer. Update your links with class instead id. And take a look at 2 js view to find [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). It works well in *index* and *show* page in my sandbox app. So feel free to adapt to your markup.

Comment: thank you very much! I kind of see how it works now, so I have to change my routes in

    get 'like', to: "posts#like"
    get 'unlike', to: "posts#unlike"

but when you say "add an id to bind in js" where/how should I do this?

Comment: only that? I assumed there was something else to do because I had "undefined local variable or method `like_post'" (and unlike_post)

Comment: should it be id: 'like_post' with the ' ' ?

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Before, I used to be able to activate the buttons separately for every post in the Feed using a similar view with post instead of @ post and the construct "do-end" inside the link_to, but now when I click a button it changes all the other buttons (and counts) in the feed (A thing like a facebook wall) and after the first "like" when I hover on every unlike button it shows the same post.id for every post (but only the first button works)

Comment: See my edit section in my answer. If you have any problem, let me know. I can share with you my sandbox app aswell.

Comment: thank you very much for all the help, with the new code the buttons don't change all together but there is another issue:

If I have 2 posts in the home and I like Post 1 and then unlike it, when I like post 2 and I try to unlike it I unlike Post 1 instead (the view doesn't show it immediately but I see that it calls the unlike action for Post 1 and if I refresh the page the view gets updated aswell)

So basically if I have a lot of posts and I Like and then Unlike one of them, when I try to Like and then Unlike another one I unlike the first one instead

Comment: if you have time I still haven't resolved the issue with your code and the view with many buttons and I've made the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286036/ruby-on-rails-ajax-javascript-like-unlike-button-in-feed-issue-with-js

Comment: *here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251246/rails-acts-as-votable-gem-like-unlike-buttons-with-ajax