# Rails acts_as_votable using AJAX to stop page reloads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to be able to upvote using acts_as_votable without the page reloading but I'm not sure how to change the routes to make it work

Controller

```
def upvote
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @ip = request.remote_ip
    # Ipaddresstracker.delete_all
    if Ipaddresstracker.find_by(ipaddress: @ip)

    else
       Ipaddresstracker.create(:ipaddress => @ip, :upvoted => true, :upvotedcount => 1)
       @video.vote_by voter: User.first, :duplicate => true
    end
  # redirect_to :back
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to like_video_path(x), method: :get, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
```

Route

```
resources :videos do
  member do
    put "like", to: "videos#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "videos#downvote"
  end
end
```

Error

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/videos/53/like"):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route expects a `put` request. Change the `:method` option to `:put`

```
<%= link_to like_video_path(x), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
```

Comment: That gives the error ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template videos/upvote, application/upvote with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]} I'm following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251246/rails-acts-as-votable-gem-like-unlike-buttons-with-ajax but it doesn't specify what to do for the routes

Comment: You need to add a view for that action, like `views/views/upvote.js` (probably `.js.erb` so you can use your rails variables) with some javascript code to update the page.

Comment: There's some examples of the js view on the link you provided, play with that code, I don't know what's your actual view.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you had Jquery you can solve this problem by Jquery.
If not, try to change this `format.js { render layout: false }`. You need to render nothing so you can set `render :nothing => true` in your format.js block

Comment: Do what @arieljuod told you before. it solves your problem this rendering